# Publish web api on IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

If I create a small web api project and publish it to a server with IIS7.5, i can't open the site. I get an

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Someone who can help?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this question?  I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does your site have a default page?  Try putting the address to the default page in the URL.

Comment: It is a MVC 4 web api, witch have a global.asax in the root. I thing it will route to my home controller - it does in dubug mode in visual studio. If i add the global.asax as default document, I get an HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension.